# How do I terminate an infinite loop from inside of a goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm writing an app using Go that is interacting with Spotify's API and I find myself needing to use an infinite for loop to call an endpoint until the length of the returned slice is less than the limit, signalling that I've reached the end of the available entries.

For my user account, there are 1644 saved albums (I determined this by looping through without using goroutines). However, when I add goroutines in, I'm getting back 2544 saved albums with duplicates. I'm also using the semaphore pattern to limit the number of goroutines so that I don't exceed the rate limit.

I assume that the issue is with using the `active` variable rather than channels, but my attempt at that just resulted in an infinite loop

```
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
sem := make(chan bool, 20)
active := true
offset := 0
for {
    sem <- true
    if active {
        // add each new goroutine to waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() error {
            // remove from waitgroup when goroutine is complete
            defer wg.Done()
            // release the worker
            defer func() { <-sem }()
            savedAlbums, err := client.CurrentUsersAlbums(ctx, spotify.Limit(50), spotify.Offset(offset))
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            userAlbums = append(userAlbums, savedAlbums.Albums...)
            if len(savedAlbums.Albums) < 50 {
                // since the limit is set to 50, we know that if the number of returned albums
                // is less than 50 that we're done retrieving data
                active = false
                return nil
            } else {
                offset += 50
                return nil
            }
        }()
    } else {
        wg.Wait()
        break
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have uncontrolled concurrent access to `active` and `offset`: i.e., a data race, which can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Can you fetch the total number of albums first? If not, you have an inherently serial problem as you don't know if the next request is valid until the previous request is processed. (Unless you wish to eagerly over-request and halt upon receiving error(s))

Comment: Thanks for the input - see my comment on the answer below, but long story short is that the total number of albums available IS available, but not implemented into the current version of the Spotify client that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your main issue may be a misunderstanding of what the `go` keyword does; from [the docs](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Go_statements):

> A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the same address space.

So `go func() error {` **starts** the execution of the closure; it does not mean that any of the code runs immediately. In fact because, `client.CurrentUsersAlbums` will take a while,  it's likely you will be requesting the first 50 items 20 times. This can be demonstrated with a simplified version of your application ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/D1hL3k2tvxO))

```
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    sem := make(chan bool, 20)
    active := true
    offset := 0
    for {
        sem <- true
        if active {
            // add each new goroutine to waitgroup
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() error {
                // remove from waitgroup when goroutine is complete
                defer wg.Done()
                // release the worker
                defer func() { <-sem }()
                fmt.Println("Getting from:", offset)
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) // Simulate the query
                // Pretend that we got back 50 albums
                offset += 50
                if offset > 2000 {
                    active = false
                }
                return nil
            }()
        } else {
            wg.Wait()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Running this will produce somewhat unpredictable results (note that the playground caches results so try it on your machine) but you will probably see 20 X `Getting from: 0`.

A further issue is [data races](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector). Updating a variable from multiple goroutines without protection (e.g. [`sync.Mutex`](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/9)) results in undefined behaviour.

You will want to know how to fix this but unfortunately you will need to rethink your algorithm. Currently the process you are following is:

1. Set `pos` to 0
2. Get `50` records starting from `pos`
3. If we got `50` records then `pos=pos+50` and `loop back to step 2`

This is a sequential algorithm; you don't know whether you have all of the data until you have requested the previous section. I guess you could make speculative queries (and handle failures) but a better solution would be to find some way to determine the number of results expected and then split the queries to get that number of records between multiple goroutines.

Note that if you do know the number of responses then you can do something like the following ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/A9oYB6YUG2Q)):

```
noOfResultsToGet := 1644 // In the below we are getting 0-1643
noOfResultsPerRequest := 50
noOfSimultaneousRequests := 20 // You may not need this but many services will limit the number of simultaneous requests you can make (or, at least, rate limit them)

requestChan := make(chan int)       // Will be passed the starting #
responseChan := make(chan []string) // Response from whatever request we are making (can be any type really)

// Start goroutines to make the requests
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(noOfSimultaneousRequests)
for i := 0; i < noOfSimultaneousRequests; i++ {
    go func(routineNo int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for startPos := range requestChan {
            // Simulate making the request
            maxResult := startPos + noOfResultsPerRequest
            if maxResult > noOfResultsToGet {
                maxResult = noOfResultsToGet
            }
            rsp := make([]string, 0, noOfResultsPerRequest)

            for x := startPos; x < maxResult; x++ {
                rsp = append(rsp, strconv.Itoa(x))
            }
            responseChan <- rsp
            fmt.Printf("Goroutine %d handling data from %d to %d\n", routineNo, startPos, startPos+noOfResultsPerRequest)
        }
    }(i)
}
// Close the response channel when all goroutines have shut down
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(responseChan)
}()

// Send the requests
go func() {
    for reqFrom := 0; reqFrom < noOfResultsToGet; reqFrom += noOfResultsPerRequest {
        requestChan <- reqFrom
    }
    close(requestChan) // Allow goroutines to exit
}()

// Receive responses (note that these may be out of order)
result := make([]string, 0, noOfResultsToGet)
for x := range responseChan {
    result = append(result, x...)
}

// Order the results and output (results from gorouting may come back in any order)
sort.Slice(result, func(i, j int) bool {
    a, _ := strconv.Atoi(result[i])
    b, _ := strconv.Atoi(result[j])
    return a < b

})
fmt.Printf("Result: %v", result)
```

Relying on channels to pass messages often makes this kind of thing easier to think about and reduces the chance that you will make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is all really helpful. With regard to your suggestion to "determine the number of results expected", it's not currently possible with the current version of the Spotify client package that I am using, but there is a field returned that provided that information. Sounds like a much better approach!

Comment: No worries; just be careful with data races. These can be hard to detect (as seen in the other answer) and their impact is somewhat random making debugging tricky. If you ever update a shared variable in a goroutine  (and this includes using `append`!) then be sure to use a `Mutex` or equivalent. A better alternative is probably to send the results (`savedAlbums`) to a channel and combine them in another goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set offset as an args -> `go func(offset int) error {`.
2. Increment offset by 50 after calling go func
3. Change active type to `chan bool`
4. To avoid data race on `userAlbums = append(userAlbums, res...)`. We need to `create channel that same type as userAlbums`, then run for loop inside goroutine, then send the results to that channel.

this is the example : https://go.dev/play/p/yzk8qCURZFC

if applied to your code :

```golang
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
worker := 20
active := make(chan bool, worker)

for i := 0; i < worker; i++ {
    active <- true
}

// I assume the type of userAlbums is []string
resultsChan := make(chan []string, worker)

go func() {
    offset := 0
    for {
        if <-active {
            // add each new goroutine to waitgroup
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(offset int) error {
                // remove from waitgroup when goroutine is complete
                defer wg.Done()
                savedAlbums, err := client.CurrentUsersAlbums(ctx, spotify.Limit(50), spotify.Offset(offset))
                if err != nil {
                // active <- false // maybe you need this
                    return err
                }
                resultsChan <- savedAlbums.Albums
                if len(savedAlbums.Albums) < 50 {
                    // since the limit is set to 50, we know that if the number of returned albums
                    // is less than 50 that we're done retrieving data
                    active <- false
                    return nil
                } else {
                    active <- true
                    return nil
                }
            }(offset)
            offset += 50
        } else {
            wg.Wait()
            close(resultsChan)
            break
        }
    }
}()

for res := range resultsChan {
    userAlbums = append(userAlbums, res...)
}
```

Comment: Concurrency can be hard to get right; unfortunately issues remain in your code. In your example these are hidden by the `Println` (this has a synchronizing effect - [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Nlc7Rxj0UY1)). As the code in the playground, and your example above, differ significantly (one counts up, the other down) it's difficult to comment in detail. The fact remains that the algorithm is fundamentally flawed (your playground code is closer - it assumes you know the number of results in advance).

Comment: @Brits I have updated my answer. I also thought before that there would be data race on `userAlbums = append(userAlbums, res...)`. For the playground, I created it as the real answer, assume the length is from spotify so this will be decrement. I'm to lazy to import atomic :D. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Thanks - note I mainly raised this because others tend to find these results in search and just copy/paste so it's important that code is correct if at all possible (data races are horrible to debug!). I've added, what I believe to be, a simpler approach to my answer.